What is the name of the manga where mc is stronger as the story goes on?
The story is about a male mc they have these long slabs of stones with writing that you read to get to the next level and this happens in some kind starry space. The person can only read the slabs for which they have the talent like if you have space power then you can read the space principle kind of thing.

Medieval fantasy? Ancient Japan? Futuristic? Contemporary? Polynesian islands?

Full colour or mostly black & white?
